# What is the default time after which an HTTP request is deemed to have timed out?

Tags: php, http, timeout

For PHP, what is the default time after which an HTTP request is deemed to have timed out?

I'm using the PECL HTTP extension to make HTTP requests. I can set a timeout limit when making a request, however I'd like to know what the default is if nothing is explicitly specified.

I've hunted through the PHP manual to no avail. I'd appreciate answers supported by evidence, such as a link to the relevant manual page, as opposed to speculative suggestions.

I'm keen to find out what the default timeout *actually* is not just what it *probably* is. I can guess it may *probably* be 30 seconds as this seems a reasonable value, however I can find nothing to confirm or deny this.

Comment: Cross-Reference: [Does file_get_contents() have a timeout setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236166/does-file-get-contents-have-a-timeout-setting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm quite sure what you're looking for is the [default_socket_timeout](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout) php.ini option.  It appears the default is 60 seconds.

Comment: Working fine on Centos, nginx, AWS EC2. Above answer has saved my life!! Thanks @russ

Answer (score 3):

Just for future reference: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/http/trunk/http_request_api.c?view=markup

If I understood it correctly, the default timeout options values are:

- *timeout* = `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` | `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` = 0 (means "waits indefinitely")
- *connecttimeout* = `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` | `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` = 3
- *dns_cache_timeout* = `CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT` = 60