# Does file_get_contents() have a timeout setting?

Tags: php, timeout, file-get-contents

I am calling a series of links using the [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) method in a loop. Each link may take more than 15 minutes to process. Now, I worry about whether PHP's `file_get_contents()` has a timeout period?

If yes, it will time out with a call and move to next link. I don't want to call the next link without the prior one finishing.

So, please tell me whether `file_get_contents()` has a timeout period. The file which contains the `file_get_contents()` is set to [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/set_time_limit) to zero (unlimited).

Comment: Cross-Reference: [Handling delays when retrieving files from remote server in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1605063/367456)

Comment: I've experienced the same behaviour (timeout when querying URL on the same "server") inside a Visual Studio PHP project that uses the PHP Tools for Visual Studio extensions. [More information here](http://support.devsense.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=1916).

Comment: This happens also when using the [built-in PHP server to query an URL on the same website](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63102), because it is a single-threaded web server.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sabarasaba/1387550

Answer (score 357):

The default timeout is defined by [`default_socket_timeout` ini-setting](http://php.net/filesystem.configuration#ini.default-socket-timeout), which is 60 seconds. You can also change it on the fly:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 900); // 900 Seconds = 15 Minutes
```

Another way to set a timeout, would be to use [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/function.stream-context-create) to set the timeout as [HTTP context options](http://php.net/context.http) of the [HTTP stream wrapper](http://php.net/wrappers.http) in use:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
    array(
        'timeout' => 1200,  //1200 Seconds is 20 Minutes
    )
));

echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/', false, $ctx);
```

Comment: Can you give info about how to set timeout for https url?

Comment: this thing is not working perfectly, if your value is 1200, its actually is 2400. i just test it.

Comment: default_socket_timeout, stream_set_timeout, and stream_context_create timeout are all the timeout of every line read/write, not the whole connection timeout.

Answer (score 42):

As @diyism mentioned, "*default_socket_timeout, stream_set_timeout, and stream_context_create timeout are all the timeout of every line read/write, not the whole connection timeout.*" And the top answer by @stewe has failed me.

As an alternative to using `file_get_contents`, you can always use `curl` with a timeout.

So here's a working code that works for calling links.

```
$url='http://example.com/';
$ch=curl_init();
$timeout=5;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: This answer gives another approach to controlling the connect timeout (using `fsockopen` instead of `curl`): http://stackoverflow.com/a/3690321/1869825

Comment: you should set both CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT in curl. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27776164/1863432

Comment: Is not a valid response, the question is for "file_get_contents". The response is great but inapropiate.

Answer (score 35):

**Yes!** By passing a [stream context](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) in the third parameter:

Here with a timeout of ***1s***:

```
file_get_contents("https://abcedef.com", 0, stream_context_create(["http"=>["timeout"=>1]]));
```

Source in comment section of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

**[HTTP context options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php):**

```
method
header
user_agent
content
request_fulluri
follow_location
max_redirects
protocol_version
timeout
```

[Non HTTP stream contexts](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.php)

```
Socket
FTP
SSL
CURL
Phar
Context (notifications callback)
Zip
```

Comment: The timeout given in `stream_context_create` only works for connection timeout. If the server replies (sends some data) within the given timeout, but takes forever to send the rest of its payload, this timeout doesn't interrupt the slow transfer.

Answer (score 6):

It is worth noting that if changing *default_socket_timeout* on the fly, it might be useful to restore its value after your *file_get_contents* call:

```
$default_socket_timeout = ini_get('default_socket_timeout');
....
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 10);
file_get_contents($url);
...
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', $default_socket_timeout);
```

Comment: but you know that ini_set doesn't set the things permanently, right? so basically 4 half of your script is just useless

Comment: @FlashThunder Not if there is another call to file_get_contents later in the code that requires the previous timeout.
Restoring settings changed on the fly for a specific bit of code after that code has executed is generally good practice.

Comment: @FlashThunder it is good practice to restore the socket_timeout value after a call so that subsequent calls to the same function **in the same script execution** use global settings.

Comment: isn't it better to use `ini_restore('default_socket_timeout');` instead?  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-restore.php

Answer (score 1):

For me work when i change my php.ini in my host:

```
; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
default_socket_timeout = 300
```

Answer (score -2):

For prototyping, using curl from the shell with the `-m` parameter allow to pass milliseconds, and will work in both cases, either the connection didn't initiate, error 404, 500, bad url, or the whole data wasn't retrieved in full in the allowed time range, the timeout is always effective. **Php won't ever hang out**.

Simply don't pass *unsanitized* user data in the shell call.

```
system("curl -m 50 -X GET 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=LTCUSDT&interval=60' -H  'accept: application/json' > data.json");
// This data had been refreshed in less than 50ms
var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"),true));
```

Comment: never ever do that.
Aside of opening a bunch of potential security holes, depending on context, you have a full curl API in every PHP installation.

Comment: I do that all the time since years for my personal scripts, and this has never cause issues. The key part is the `-m` param. Security holes, only if using unsanitized user data, as warned. This is btw the sole one liner that fully works on all this answers. Read again.

Comment: PHP doesn't have curl built-in unlike what you are believing, you have to install the separated package `php-curl`. But shell curl is always available.

Comment: The PHP environment of anyone asking this question does have libcurl available, anyone who doesn't probably doesn't need to ask that question.
Using such shell executions is the dirtiest way you could write something.

Comment: `Using such shell executions is the dirtiest way you could write something` Ha ha are you serious with this statment. Basically saying that bash is dirty. Or Linux is dirty. See my other answer here for a pure php way. Still not as reliable as what I am showing here.

Comment: I agree with @NVRM, as long as you know what you're doing there's nothing wrong with calling a shell script / bash from PHP. The only pain is that it's a bit trickier to process any output (STDOUT, STDERR) and the fact that's probably not portable.

Comment: However, it's always preferable to use direct API calls (such as `curl_*`), as these provide easier management of configuration etc.

Comment: Sure of course, it is not recommended, maybe *dirty*, but I left a proper way as answer on this page already `stream_context()`. Again calling the shell curl does solve the problem raised in the comment by @z80crew `timeout doesn't interrupt the slow transfer. ` . That's right, and using the `-m` param in the shell call to curl, as shown on this answer, is efficiently timing out as expected on every conditions. Also using php-curl does not enhance the single threading normal behaviour of PHP and may cause latencies.

Comment: I don't think it's _dirty_, sometimes using the shell is the only way to access a third party module/program.