# Set connection time out in simplexml_load_file in php

Tags: php, timeout, simplexml

I have get weather from remote web using `simplexml_load_file()` function.

It's works fine in normal condition.But when Internet is not available then my script wait for long time for response.

I have execute php page from embedded board not from browser.

So I want to put time out for that.

Is it possible to put connection time out in `simplexml_load_file()` ?

If any other alternative then please tell me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to increase the timeout in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829403/how-to-increase-the-timeout-in-php)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Not duplicate see my question again

Comment: Duplicate of [Set time out on simplexml_load_file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399610/set-time-out-on-simplexml-load-file/32586480)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the PHP function called `set_time_limit()`, which allows you to cap the execution time of a PHP script.

Comment: Hey is it work when I will execute php page from embedded board ?

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't. `set_time_limit()` is a native PHP function, so it should work regardless of the hardware you're running it on, unless you are running a special version of PHP. Even then, I doubt this function would be excluded from a special version because of the potential importance it could play in an embedded system.