# How can I interrupt a PHP function that's taking too long?

Tags: php, xml, windows, function

I would like to stop a simplexml_load_file if it takes too long to load and/or isn't reachable (occasionally the site with the xml goes down) seeing as I don't want my site to completely lag if theirs aren't up.

I tried to experiment a bit myself, but haven't managed to make anything work.

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399610/set-time-out-on-simplexml-load-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an arbitrary function quit after a specified time. What you can do instead is to try to load the contents of the URL first - and if it succeeds, continue processing the rest of the script.

There are several ways to achieve this. The easiest is to use `file_get_contents()` with a stream context set:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('timeout' => 5)));

$xmlStr = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context);
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
```

Or you could use a stream context with [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_file) via the [`libxml_set_streams_context()`](http://php.net/libxml_set_streams_context) function:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('timeout' => 5)));

libxml_set_streams_context($context);
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

You could wrap it as a nice little function:

```
function simplexml_load_file_from_url($url, $timeout = 5)
{
    $context = stream_context_create(
        array('http' => array('timeout' => (int) $timeout))
    );
    $data = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context);

    if(!$data) {
        trigger_error("Couldn't get data from: '$url'", E_USER_NOTICE);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return simplexml_load_string($data);
}
```

Alternatively, you can consider using the [cURL](http://php.net/curl) (available by default). The benefit of using cURL is that you get really fine grained control over the request and how to handle the response.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `stream context` with a `timeout` option coupled with `file_get_contents`

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('timeout' => 5))); //<---- Setting timeout to 5 seconds...
```

and now map that to your `file_get_contents`

```
$xml_load = file_get_contents('http://yoururl', FALSE, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_load);
```

Comment: You can also use `libxml_set_streams_context($context);` prior to calling `simplexml_load_file` to achieve this.

Comment: btw, +1 for pointing into the right direction. Maybe you can add `libxml_set_streams_context` as Amal suggested?

Comment: @hek2mgl, I never tried that ..I wish if Amal edits this answer.

Comment: @AmalMurali Maybe you can finish this *collaborative* work? Greetings to India from Berlin! :)

Comment: @hek2mgl: Didn't want to change this answer radically, so I've added [my own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22413629/1438393).

Comment: I get "Warning: stream_context_create(): options should have the form ["wrappername"]["optionname"] = $value" when trying this. Any idea why?

Comment: @user3397543, Seems like there was a wrong mapping on the `context_create`. I have fixed that. It works now and am glad that you found an answer.