# Is file_get_contents() a blocking function?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, blocking

I am connecting to an unreliable API via file_get_contents.  Since it's unreliable, I decided to put the api call into a while loop thusly:

```
$resultJSON = FALSE;

while(!$resultJSON) {
    $resultJSON = file_get_contents($apiURL);
    set_time_limit(10);
}
```

Putting it another way: Say the API fails twice before succeeding on the 3rd try.  Have I sent 3 requests, or have I sent however many hundreds of requests as will fit into that 3 second window?

Comment: I think it's a typo for `set_time_limit`. (A PHP builtin.)

Comment: Ah.  `set_time_limit(10)` says, "if you are still stuck in this while loop after 10 seconds, abort."

Comment: AFAIK using `file_get_contents()` on a URL is usually a pretty terrible idea. In your case you should probably be using [cURL and one or more timeout options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks.  I'm curious though as to what the problem is with `file_get_contents()` for a URL

Comment: If you want contents (response), then it is blocking. Set time limit is pointless here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`file_get_contents()`, like basically all functions in PHP, is a blocking call.

Comment: If you want to wait for response, which in this case, he wants.

Comment: There is no non-blocking version of the call. (Nor would it even make sense to have one.)

Comment: `file_get_contents` is shorthand for fopen/fread/fclose, which supports URL too. But that is not the only way to read URL with PHP (without cURL etc.), non-blocking mode can be achieved with `fsockopen`, `STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT`, and/or `stream_set_blocking`. There is nothing wrong with your answer, I'm just saiyan. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a blocking function. You should also check to see if the value is specifically "false". (Note that === is used, not ==.) Lastly, you want to sleep for 10 seconds. set_time_limit() is used to set the max execution time before it is automatically killed.

```
set_time_limit(300); //Run for up to 5 minutes.

$resultJSON = false;
while($resultJSON === false)
{
    $resultJSON = file_get_contents($apiURL);
    sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: It does return false.  From the manual: "The function returns the read data or FALSE on failure." http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php.  EDIT: Oh, sorry, nevermind, I now see what you meant.

Comment: Yes, but your check did not check for a false exclusively. Using "!" is too lose in this case, because of the content that could be returned.

Comment: Is the missing $ in the second resultJSON on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Sammitch suggestion to use cURL instead of `file_get_contents()`:

```
<?php
$apiURL = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';

$curlh = curl_init($apiURL);
// Use === not ==
// if ($curlh === FALSE) handle error;
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); // maybe, up to you
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); // or TRUE, according to your needs
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
// set your timeout in seconds here
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$resultJSON = curl_exec($curlh);
curl_close($curlh);
// if ($resultJSON === FALSE) handle error;
echo "$resultJSON\n"; // Now process $resultJSON
?>
```

There are a lot more `curl_setopt` options. [You should check them out.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Of course, this assumes [you have cURL available](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php).

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any function in PHP that does not "block". As an alternative, and if your server permits such things, you can:

1. Use `pcntl_fork()` and do other stuff in your script while waiting for the API call to go through.
2. Use `exec()` to call another script in the background [using `&`] to do the API call for you if `pcntl_fork()` is unavailable.

However, if you literally cannot do anything else in your script without a successful call to that API then it doesn't really matter if the call 'blocks' or not. What you should really be concerned about is spending so much time waiting for this API that you exceed the configured `max_execution_time` and your script is aborted in the middle without being properly completed.

```
$max_calls = 5;
for( $i=1; $i<=$max_calls; $i++ ) {
    $resultJSON = file_get_contents($apiURL);
    if( $resultJSON !== false ) {
        break;
    } else if( $i = $max_calls ) {
        throw new Exception("Could not reach API within $max_calls requests.");
    }
    usleep(250000); //wait 250ms between attempts
}
```

It's worth noting that `file_get_contents()` [has a default timeout of ***60 seconds***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236166/php-file-get-contents-have-time-out) so you're really in danger of the script being killed. Give serious consideration to using cURL instead since you can set much more reasonable timeout values.

Comment: Well, the API is consistent in that it returns a response promptly, so I don't think I need to worry about the 60 second timeout limit. The problem is that about 1/3 of the time that response is an 500 internal server error.  I was looking for a way to keep asking for a response, while avoiding the possibility of getting stuck in a loop. Your code here addresses _that_ problem very nicely, thanks!

Comment: Ahh, *that* kind of unreliable. I'd still recommend cURL, though, as you can retrieve the HTTP response code and take action if you get something other than a 200 or 500, indicating a different problem than usual.