# PHP redirect if failed to open stream

Tags: php, redirect, file-get-contents

I am using `file_get_contents` to fetch data from a 3rd party, however the 3rd party is experiencing a DDOS attack at the moment and therefore, most of my sites functionality is lost.

How can I set a redirect to another page if opening the stream fails?

Comment: check for  empty(file_get_contents ) and redirect with php

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
$url = "http://example.com/url";

$response = get_headers($url);
if($response[0] === 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
   // Request response is OK
   $content = file_get_contents($url);
} else {
   // if header response is NOT OK redirect...
   header("Location: someUrlGoesHere"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change the default timeout, then redirect on failure.**

You can change the default timeout used for `file_get_contents` like so:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 10); // 10 seconds
```

We need to do this, because the default timeout is 60 seconds - and your visitors won't want to wait that long.

Then you just test if the request went ok, and redirect based on that...

```
$request = file_get_contents($url);
if( !$request )
   header("Location: http://someurl.com/");
exit;
```

(Remember to exit after a redirect, or sometimes code after that still gets executed).

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect it with header().

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents($attackedUrl);
if(!$data)
   header("Location: $pageToRedirect");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Add validation!

First, there's [several methods to check if a file exists on a remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php).

Second, if you fetch data using `file_get_contents`, you can add validation to check if it's the full data you expected (other answers / comments mention checking using `empty`, or checking for a falsey value. It's up to you how you do this though, as there's no context provided about the type of data received). [You can also set a timeout value in case it takes too long to fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236166/does-file-get-contents-have-a-timeout-setting)!

And to redirect, you can use [PHP's `header` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), like so:

```
header('Location: http://my.redirected/page/href');
```

However, **`header()` will not work if you have already outputted content.**, so please make sure you check through your script for echo / print lines before running `header`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.is-file.php

```
<?php 
$url = "../../filename.php";
if (is_file($url))
     echo "File Exist!";
    //$request = file_get_contents($url);
    //print(filesize($url))." ko";
else
     echo "File not Exist!";
?>
```