# PHP - Setting a file_get_contents timeout

Tags: php, arrays, function, http-headers, file-get-contents

I am using `file_get_contents` to get a headers of an external page to determine if the external page is online like so:

```
$URL = "http://page.location/";
$Context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => 'GET',
)
));
file_get_contents($URL, false, $Context);
$ResponseHeaders = $http_response_header;

$header = substr($ResponseHeaders[0], 9, 3);

if($header[0] == "5" || $header[0] == "4"){
//do stuff
}
```

This is working well except when the page is taking too long to respond.

How do I set a timeout?

Will `file_get_headers` return **FALSE** if it has not completed yet and will PHP move to the next line if it has not completed the `file_get_contents` request?

Comment: A similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236166/does-file-get-contents-have-a-timeout-setting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a `timeout` key inside the `stream_context_array`

```
$Context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'timeout' => 30, //<---- Here (That is in seconds)
)
));
```

---

#### Your Question....

> will file_get_headers return FALSE if it has not completed yet and
> will PHP move to the next line if it has not completed the
> file_get_contents request?

**Yes** , it will return FALSE along with the below warning message as shown.

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
> properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
> failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. I found this great tool for testing which might be useful for anyone reading this question. http://www.seanshadmand.com/2012/06/21/fake-response-server-slow-response-time-generator/

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example of how can you set the timeout for this function:

```
<?php
$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 1
        )
    )
);
file_get_contents("http://example.com/", 0, $ctx);
?>
```