# Set time out for part of php script

Tags: php, file

sorry for my English

I use `file_get_contents` function to get the HTML content of "www.example.com" as string and then process this string.

My problem is when this website take a lot of time to open, I want to set time out for a part of my script (not all script) so that if `file_get_contents` function take much time, my script will stop it and continue to next lines.
**I am using php5**
is it possible to do this, I appreciate all your suggestions

example:

```
//set time out =  10S
$siteStr = @file_get_contents("www.example.com");
//10S is finished so stop file_get_contents and continue
```

Answer (score 1):

use curl

```
 function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 10;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: sorry but curl module not activated on my server and i don't have access to activate it. I must use file_get_content

Comment: so look on the comments, 10x

Comment: thanks man I found the solution in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236166/does-file-get-contents-have-a-timeout-setting