# When does timeout in stream_context_create not work?

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract a small amount of data from another website but I am finding that it is timing out. I've put some coding clauses in place to try and force my code to obtain data from a similar data if trying to obtain it from the first takes too long.

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('timeout' => 2)));

$geo = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, 0, $ctx), true);
```

In principle this should time out after 2 seconds and then I'll know its duff and go for the second URL. But it doesn't work, and tries to get it for 15 seconds. I've tried recplacing the $ctx with

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 2);
```

But this doesn't work either. Can anyone please suggest something else I could try?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? As timeout was only added in version 5.2.1 http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#refsect1-context.http-changelog

Comment: The version is 5.4.33

Answer (score 0):

In my case when the URL begins with https the timeout does not work. But when I removed the s from the end of the https it worked. If you can allow your script to use the non secure protocol your problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

There is another way you can set the timeout..

It would be with [stream_context_create()](https://www.php.net/function.stream-context-create.php).

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
array(
    'timeout' => 1200, // 1 200 Seconds = 20 Minutes
)
));

echo file_get_contents('the link', false, $ctx);
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236166/does-file-get-contents-have-a-timeout-setting)