# cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 5001 milliseconds

Tags: php, linux, curl, centos, directadmin

I use WordPress and I recently moved my site from the cpanel host to a Linux server with directadmin panel.
Right after the transfer realized that customers have the following error when downloading via EDD plugin.

> cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 5001 milliseconds

I also got this error of w3_total_cache plugin.

Server informatin:
Centos 6.8 (Final)
cURL 7.54.0 (Final)
directadmin

Answer (score 5):

`cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 5001 milliseconds` means **`DNS resolving failed`**.

> so just change the DNS server list in **/etc/resolv.conf**.
>
> or maybe we can bind the hostname and ip address in **/etc/hosts**.

<del>this image shows the demo.</del>

Answer (score 0):

As reported here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/dropbox-upload-fails-with-curl-timeout-error/
You can apply this temporary fix to extend the HTTP request timeout:

```
add_filter( 'http_request_timeout', function( $timeout ) { return 60; });
```

Wordpress default is 5 seconds.

Answer (score -2):

To resolve this you have to set the curl connection time out and time out value at the time of curl initialization.
Just changes this two property value.

```
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
```

For more details check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776129/php-curl-curlopt-connecttimeout-vs-curlopt-timeout).

Answer (score -3):

update these two lines here:
`/usr/share/icingaweb2/modules/jira/library/Jira/RestApi.php`

```
    $opts = array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => $this->url($url),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $auth,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => \strtoupper($method),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
```

Answer (score -4):

You can set 
**set_time_limit(120);**
in the **wp-config.php** after the **MySQL settings** section.