# Docker container can't download WordPress installation files automatically

Tags: docker-compose

I have the following compose file:

```
version: "3"        
services:
    wordpress:
        image: visiblevc/wordpress
        privileged: true
        network_mode: bridge #should help?
        # required for mounting bindfs
        cap_add:
            - SYS_ADMIN
        devices:
            - /dev/fuse
        # required on certain cloud hosts
        security_opt:
            - apparmor:unconfined
        ports:
            - 8080:80
            - 8081:443
      ...WP parameters ommitted for brewity
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

[image]

When I use the CLI and *curl the SAME url*, I can download the information.

[image]

What should I change in the yaml to make it work automatically?

**UPDATE:**

As curl works manually, I don't think it as a DNS resolve error, but to make sure, I modified the *resolv.conf* file to a valid nameserver address:

[image]

Unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: This is DNS issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082832/curl-error-28-resolving-timed-out-after-5001-milliseconds

Comment: @vsergi If it is a DNS issue, then curl would fail when using manually. I checked, curl can resolve any address when using in CLI.

Comment: Yes, you are right.... Still, the message in the console is related to DNS resolution issue...But it does not make much sense then...

Answer (score 1):

Try to put on image this:

```
image: visiblevc/wordpress:latest
```

You need to specify the tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, this changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

We checked the [initialization shell script](https://github.com/visiblevc/wordpress-starter/blob/master/run.sh) of the Docker image.
We couldn't determine why the resolve fails when `wp core download` was called so we created a *workaround.*

We added a pre-init section inside the script to use the explicit curl commands that worked as demonstrated in the CLI. As a sideeffect, we download the necessary files so it bypasses the need of downloading and the potential resolve timeout.
*Note: we needed several curl calls for the API as the resolve kept failing after only one call.*

This is how the new script starts:

```
h1 Pre-init
    curl "https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/?locale=en_US" >/dev/null
    curl "https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-5.9.3.zip" --output wordpress-5.9.3.zip
    curl "https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/?locale=en_US" >/dev/null
    curl "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/classic-editor.1.6.2.zip" --output classic-editor.1.6.2.zip
    curl "https://downloads.wordpress.org/translation/core/5.9.3/hu_HU.zip" --output hu_HU.zip    
    curl "https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/?locale=en_US" >/dev/null
h1 'Begin WordPress Installation'
```

Using this script, the installation succeeded.