# magento 2 e curl timeout, main.CRITICAL: Operation timed out after 252 milliseconds

Tags: php, magento2

Does anyone know why I get this error in Magento 2?
I have not limited  execution time in php.ini

main.CRITICAL: Operation timed out after 252 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Operation timed out after 252 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received at /var/www/vhosts/test/vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php:427)"} []

thanks

Comment: Hello, for readers to help, you should add details about what you've already tried, why it didn't worked. Or results from your research that you don't know how to implement. I'm pretty sure that Googling about your error message and tracing your error should give results.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `execution_time` related. It's curl config itself. See more here [PHP cURL: CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT vs CURLOPT_TIMEOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776129/php-curl-curlopt-connecttimeout-vs-curlopt-timeout)