# Will file_get_contents timeout if the url it's trying to call is being DDOS attacked and slow to respond?

Tags: php

Will the following code timeout after 2 seconds IF the url it's calling is hung up by a DDOS attack?

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array( 
                                    'http' => array( 
                                        'timeout' => 2,

                                        ) 
                                    ) 
                                ); 


$data = @file_get_contents( $urlPrimary, 0, $ctxPrimary )
```

Comment: it wont detect a "DDOS" but simple lack of availability

Comment: never use `@` to suppress warnings & errors. Handle them properly. If you want to have more control of the request, use cURL .

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236166/does-file-get-contents-have-a-timeout-setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server is unable to provide the full response within the 2 seconds, file_get_contents() will return FALSE.

Comment: which you can adjust by `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 900);`