# if file_get_contents timeout, do something else

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-ini

I have a piece of code for file_get_contents and it works fine, but sometimes the source URL does not respond and because of that my page does not load for 60 seconds (after default timeout). 
I want to set 5 seconds timeout for file_get_contents to do something else if the source URL does not respond in 5 seconds.
this is my code:

```
  <?php 
$url = 'https://www.example.com';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div class="js-price-value">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );
$second_step[0]= str_replace( " ", "",  $second_step[0]);
if (strlen(trim($second_step[0]))!==0) {
 $price=$second_step[0];

 echo $price;  

}else {
   echo '<div>something else</div>'
};
?>
```

I want something like this after above code:

```
if source url dose not respond in 5 seconds
{
do something else
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does file\_get\_contents() have a timeout setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236166/does-file-get-contents-have-a-timeout-setting)

Comment: Please select an answer to help users with the same issue find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Answer:** 
I saw this topic before
[Does file_get_contents() have a timeout setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236166/does-file-get-contents-have-a-timeout-setting)
but it wasn't exactly what I want. I wanted to do something else if the timeout happens.
so I used this code:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
   'http' => array(
       'timeout' => 5
       )
   )
);
$url = 'source URL';
$content = file_get_contents("$url", 0, $ctx);
if(!$content){
   echo 'timeout happened';

}elseif (another condition) {
   echo 'condition result'

}else {
   echo 'something else'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
file_get_contents("https://abcedef.com", 0, stream_context_create(["http"=>["timeout"=>1]]));
```

src: [Does file_get_contents() have a timeout setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236166/does-file-get-contents-have-a-timeout-setting)

Flagging question as duplicate for removal.